# Python sort "names" in pd.DataFrame by last year of activity

Tags: python, pandas, filter

Hello stackoverflow community,

I have a df with >300 entries. The df shows the years in which various authors/ researchers have been actively submitting publications in one specific research project.
The data looks like the following:

```
Author     Name of Publication     Year
Name A   Pub A                   1998
Name B   Pub B                   2005
Name C   Pub A                   1998
Name A   Pub C                   2000
etc...
```

As authors have made multiple publications while being active in the project, the df contains multiple entries with their names.
I would now like to filter the earliest year of activity of an author as well as his/her last year of activity. Goal is to derive the timespan of activity per author.

But currently I really dont know how to apply a proper filter.
In order to derive the max-values per author, the code I was using to filter the df was:

```
     df.groupby('author')['year'].aggregate(pd.Series.idxmax)
```

Afterwards I would have applied the same line for filtering the min values.
Unfortunately the output says "reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype."

Can anyone tell me what I've overseen / how to write a filter that actually does its job?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sort the dataframe by date, and then use `agg` with `first` and `last` to extract the earliest and latest years of activity:

```
df.sort_values('Year').groupby('Author')['Year'].agg(['first', 'last'])

        first  last
Author             
Name A   1998  2000
Name B   2005  2005
Name C   1998  1998
```

You could then put those results back into your original dataframe using `join` if you want:

```
new_df = (df.set_index('Author')
          .join(df.sort_values('Year')
                .groupby('Author')
                .agg({'Year':['first', 'last']})))

>>> new_df
       Name of Publication  Year  (Year, first)  (Year, last)
Author                                                       
Name A               Pub A  1998           1998          2000
Name A               Pub C  2000           1998          2000
Name B               Pub B  2005           2005          2005
Name C               Pub A  1998           1998          1998
```